# Populating array with random points

Tags: c++, arrays, performance-testing, stack-overflow, bitwise-operators

I have an assignment:

The three planes X=0, Y=0, and Z=0 divide the 3D space into 8 octant domains. Given an
array of 3D points, the following function counts the number of points belonging to each
octant. Write a version of that function which doesn’t use either if-statements or the if operator.

The function:

```
typedef float pnt[3];

void count(pnt const* pnts, const int n, unsigned cnt[8]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cnt[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) ++cnt[7]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][2] < 0.0f) ++cnt[3]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][1] < 0.0f && pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) ++cnt[5]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][1] < 0.0f && pnts[i][2] < 0.0f) ++cnt[1]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] < 0.0f && pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) ++cnt[6]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] < 0.0f && pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f && pnts[i][2] < 0.0f) ++cnt[2]; else
        if (pnts[i][0] < 0.0f && pnts[i][1] < 0.0f && pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) ++cnt[4]; else
        ++cnt[0];
    }
}
```

Rest of the assignment:

Also implement the missing code for populating an array of random points and compare the
performance of the two versions (with and without if statements) assuming n = 2^24.
(hint: each bit in the octant index of a point is associated to one dimension).

I am stuck at populating an array to the function. I have tried different ways and none of them have worked and results in stack overflow. Either I am misunderstanding the assignment or I am doing something wrong with my code:

I am trying to populate my array with random values and sending it to the function like this:

```
unsigned cnt[8];

pnt arr[(1 << 24)];

for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 24) - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = (rand() % 100) - 50;
    }
}
    
count(arr, 1 << 24, cnt);
```

This code gives me stack overflow in debug mode. In release mode I don't get any errors but also it does not even touch my for loop or working with my count function.

I know that pnt arr[(1 << 24)] is alot of space in memory and I also understand that I get stack overflow because that is too much memory allocated for the array but how should I interpret " assuming n = 2^24"?

Comment: `pnt arr[(1 << 24)];` will (try to) create an array of 16777216 `pnt`s on the stack. That's probably 67'108'864 bytes. Unless you have very large stacks, you need to find an alternative.

Comment: Do you know about any other way to create memory, maybe not on the stack?

Comment: The heap? Will look into that

Comment: `std::vector<pnt> arr(1U << 24);` may work.

Comment: Btw, I didn't notice your `typedef` was to a `float[3]` before. You could make it nicer by defining a `pnt` as `struct pnt { float x, y, z; };`. That makes it easier to add member functions that can help you in the later calculations.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not supposed to change that code because it is an assignment :/

Comment: @Leon Are you saying that you aren't allowed to change `typedef float pnt[3];` into a `struct`?

Comment: yes, I am not allowed to change the code provided to me

Answer (score 3):

To populate array drop use of c-arrays. In your scenario they are to big to be stored on stack (as you noticed).

So just use `std::vector` to hold this values.

```cpp
using Point = std::array<float, 3>;
using Points = std::vector<Point>;
using DomainCount = std::array<unsigned, 8>;

Points generateRandomData(std::size_t n)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis{-50, 50};

    Points data;
    data.reserve(n);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data), n, [dis, &gen]() {
        return Point{dis(gen), dis(gen), dis(gen)};
    };
}
```

If youi need old API (which is look like very old C style) you can do this:

```cpp
auto data = generateRandomData(1 << 24);
count(data.data(), data.size(), cnt);
```

To drop if-s you need use fact that `bool` expression is implicitly converted to `0` or `1` integer value.

```cpp
using Point = std::array<float, 3>;
using Points = std::vector<Point>;
using DomainCount = std::array<unsigned, 8>;

DomainCount count(const Points& points) {
    DomainCount r{};

    for (const auto& p : points) {
        auto xIndex = p[0] < 0;
        auto yIndex = static_cast<int>(p[1] < 0) << 1;
        auto zIndex = static_cast<int>(p[2] < 0) << 2;
        
        ++r[xIndex + yIndex + zIndex];
    }
    return r;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YGaxnY6Pz

Note technique is called branchless programing and leads to code which is faster then `if` version (unpredictable branches are hard task for CPU).

Comment: For this specific example, this code solved it without ifs: ```int index = (pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f) + (pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f) * 2 + (pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) * 4;
  cnt[index]++;```

Comment: this is matter of preferred coding style. Whatever works for you. I agree multiplication looks better: https://godbolt.org/z/cKbTeKen9

Comment: From a speed performance perspective. Is it better to use bitwise operators in this case? Because when comparing my two solutions I dont get a significant difference between the two. For the solution with if statements, I get the speed to be 326ms and for the solution with multiplication above I get 277ms. That is not a big difference

Comment: Remembered that in C and C++ there is "AS IF RULE". This means that compiler has right to transform code wherever it likes as long as visible effects of running this code remain unchanged. This means that it doesn't meter if you use multiplication or bit shift operation, for compiler it is same logic and it most probably generate exactly same code. So use whatever is more readable for you. I recommend you to watch some talks from Matt Godbolt, who shows what kind of wonders compiler can do.

Comment: If you are doing teasing by yourself please remember to do that with optimization enabled. So feed options like `-O3` to a compiler. If you use debug mode then compiler does everything literally as it is written.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating to the heap solved it.

```
pnt* arr = new pnt [(1 << 24)];

for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 24) - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = (rand() % 100) - 50;
    }
}

count(arr, 1 << 24, cnt);
```

Comment: Don't use `new` when you have a perfectly solid container to do this: `std::vector<pnt> arr(1U << 24);`